# Validation error less than training error

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, cross-validation, model-evaluations, model-selection

[image: Model architecture]
[image: training and computing error]
[image: printing error]

entire project link: [Github Repository](https://github.com/dipenpandit/diabetes-prediction)

In a classification task using Neural Network, I computed the fraction of misclassification as an error. And I am getting a validation error less than the training error?
I was trying to find the model with the lowest validation error and select that model. I found the validation error to be less than the training error which is unusual.

Comment: Hi @DipenPandit, welcome to the site. There are other answers on this site addressing this very same question, for instance: [Validation loss is lower than the training loss](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39661/validation-loss-is-lower-than-the-training-loss)